# Undefined route error in ember js for transition to same route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

In EmberJs am in a route say xyz.abc(#/xyz/abc). There is a tab in this page which points to the same route i.e.

```
{{#link-to 'xyz.abc'}}Tab Name{{/link-to}}
```

Clicking on this link I get the below error:

**

> There is no route named undefined at Object.handlersFor

**

Why an error for that? This happens when we do transitionTo or replaceWith to the current-route, this is needed while doing this.refresh() in application.

Comment: this [is working](https://ember-twiddle.com/b301dde7e2894146ab7443e4ee4de2d4?openFiles=templates.xyz.abc.hbs%2C&route=%2Fxyz%2Fabc)

Comment: Can you show demo @wallop?

Comment: Yep will provide a JSBin soon